# Folding of thin gauge metal sheets

Tags: mechanical-engineering, metal-folding

I would like to fold thin metal sheets to a particular angle.

For example: fold a 0.1mm thick steel strip of width 20mm and length 150mm to an angle of 45° along its length (10mm panels on each side of the fold).

I would like to keep the radius of the fold as small as possible, ideally on the order of the thickness or smaller. I would also like to do this on a bench top. I plan to use a range of thicknesses, up to 1mm thickness. But I am flexible on this constraint (but need to use thicknesses <1mm).

Are there any tools/machines which can do this in a repeatable way (ideally with 1-2° variation or less)? Are there any standards for this type of forming?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I would like to fold thin metal sheets to a particular angle.

It sounds like you're looking for a [sheet metal brake](https://www.northerntool.com/shop/tools/product_7825_7825).

[image]

I'm sure you can find less expensive models elsewhere.  Lots of places rent them too.
Heck, with the thicknesses you're using, you can make one with some hardwood and hinges.

Comment: I would just add, for the thicknesses involved, you could probably *make* your own bench top brake out of some hardwood, hinges, and some clamps.